# Java how to add a library or API while compiling with command line?

Tags: java, api, compilation, compiler-errors

The question says it all, I am trying to use an external library in my code, but it tells me that the packages I referenced to don't exist so I'm guessing the imports don't work. How do I do this?

Comment: try setting the classpath using `java -cp libs/library.jar`

Comment: also, command line does not mean you cannot use Ant or Maven (or other build systems).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-cp` option as described in the [javac notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options).

> Specify where to find user class files, and (optionally) annotation processors and source files. This class path overrides the user class path in the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. If neither `CLASSPATH`, `-cp` nor `-classpath` is specified, the user class path consists of the current directory. ..

Answer (score 2):

use --classpath both while compiling and running. If you use eclipse you can just
go to properties->Java buildpath->add external jars. And you are done.